# Optimized LINQ to SQL Query

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, query-optimization

I'm working on a vehicle tracking project and I m making Stoppage Report which looks like below:
[image: View]

And few database fields of interest looks like:

[image]

Now my current logic for the report is very poor. I fetch all the records for the selected date range and then display the records where Ignition is off and speed is equal to zero.

I seriously believe this could be optimized. Is it possible to have a LINQ query in which I only fetch the records that i need. For example in the current snap shot I want only 47890 and 47878 id record.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Here is the Code:

```
        var vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(vehicleId);
        DateTime startDate = fromDate;
        DateTime endDate = toDate.AddDays(1);
        var sData = db.Vehicles
            .Where(v => v.VehicleId == vehicleId)
            .SelectMany(v => v.GsmDeviceLogs)
            .Where(gs => gs.DateTimeOfLog > startDate && gs.DateTimeOfLog < endDate && gs.Speed < zeroSpeed && !gs.IgnitionOn)
            .Select(v => new
            {
                DateTimeOfLog = v.DateTimeOfLog,
                Location = v.Location
            }).OrderBy(gs => gs.DateTimeOfLog).ToList();
```

Comment: What about just adding the additional filter to the where filter that you already seem to have?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it. Please check my query in the edit.